# Visual Studio 2015 Publish 'Error : Copying file' gulp revision rename of js bundle at pre-build

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, gulp

The issue in essence seems to be that during a publish of an .NET MVC4 application Visual Studio throws an error with expecting to copy an existing bundle filename that gulp is removing and adding back with a new revision # in the file name. Even though the gulp event is "pre-build". Below is a a detailed desciption of the occurence.

We have a Visual Studio 2015 MVC project setup to run a pre-build event which calls a npm cmd for gulp. Gulp is minifying and bundling assets conditionally on the $(ConfigurationName). When built as Release gulp tasks includes a gulp-rev cmd to append a hashset to the bundle file name to counter caching issues.  Here is the pre-build event:

```
cd $(ProjectDir)
call npm install
call npm run $(ConfigurationName)
```

Sidenote: The csproj is configured to include this bundle using a wildcard(*) for the name.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="Areas\**\modules\dist\*.min.js" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Builds compile successfully in release. However an issue arises with publishing. We receive this error:

> Copying file
>   C:\MyProject\Areas\Quality\modules\dist\documents-used-9ed3bdf4c9.bundle.min.js
>   to
>   obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Areas\Quality\modules\dist\scripts-9ed3bdf4c9.bundle.min.js
>   failed. Could not find file
>   'Areas\Quality\modules\dist\scripts-9ed3bdf4c9.bundle.min.js'.

The build output for the publish is as such:

> 1>  MyProject-> C:\workspace\MyProject\MyProject\bin\MyProject.dll
>   2>------ Publish started: Project: MyProject, Configuration: Release
>   Any CPU ------ 2>Connecting to C:\publish... 2>Copying all files to
>   temporary location below for package/publish:
>   2>obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp. 2>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3003,5):
>   Error : Copying file
>   Areas\Quality\modules\dist\scripts-9ed3bdf4c9.bundle.min.js to
>   obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Areas\Quality\modules\dist\scripts-9ed3bdf4c9.bundle.min.js
>   failed. Could not find file
>   'Areas\Quality\modules\dist\scripts-9ed3bdf4c9.bundle.min.js'.

Notes:

1. Manually deleting the target published and project generated bundle files fixes the issue and results in a successful publish.
2. Setting Items to Deploy to "All files in this project" in the csproj fixes the issue but is not a valid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was solved by setting the ItemGroup's Target to AfterBuild

```
   <Target Name="AfterBuild"> 
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="Areas\**\Views\**\dist.cshtml" />
      <Content Include="Areas\**\modules\dist\*" />
      <Content Include="Areas\**\modules\dist\maps\*" /> 
    </ItemGroup>
   </Target>
```

This causes the paths to be analyzed and included after the build is conducted and Gulp has rendered the revisioned files. See [MSBuild MSDN Target](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka.aspx).

Also note that to get the rendered js files in the outdir of an msbuild cmd needed to set

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <UseWPP_CopyWebApplication>True</UseWPP_CopyWebApplication>
    <PipelineDependsOnBuild>False</PipelineDependsOnBuild>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

in the csproj. There is already a post describing this [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752293/msbuild-determine-a-solutions-publishedwebsites)